# how to find partial match in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am looking to find all the users who have some kind of email in a database:

```
'user' :
            {         
             'properties': 
                {
                    'user_name': { 'type': 'string', 'index' : 'not_analyzed' }, 
                    'about': { 'type': 'object' },
                }
            }
```

The about field is a JSON object, which might look like:

```
{"nickname":"bobby McBob", "contact":"bobmcbob@gmail.com", "hobbies":"tennis"}
```

but has no predetermined structure.

I would like to find all the users who have a string, in a manner that would fit the pattern *@*.com, hoping this will return all those that have email.

How do I go about doing that?

even a simple query, meant to find gmails, such as

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/index_name/user/_search' -d '{"query":{"match":{"_all":"gmail.com"}}}'
```

does not work. Maybe I should have analyzed the object "about" with a different analyzer upon indexing? to separate/tokenize it?

should I use a different query maybe?

How do I go about doing that?

Comment: Does it mean that you just want to find the documents that have a value for the contact field? Any value except the null values?

Comment: no, not any value. if the value is a street address, or a phone number for example, I am not interested in returning it. Just those that have actuall email addresses

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pattern tokenizer` to capture the pattern `abc.com` and use it in your analyzer for field `about` (`analyzer_emaildomain`). E.g:

```
"analysis":{
        "analyzer":{
          "analyzer_emaildomain": {
                    "tokenizer": "emaildomain_tokenizer"
           }
        },
         "tokenizer" : {
            "emaildomain_tokenizer" : {
                "type": "pattern",
                "pattern" : "\\b[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.com)\\b",
                "group":1
            }
        }
}
```

You can see in the settings, I captured group #1, which is any alphabetic chars that after `@` and end with `.com`, and will capture `gmail.com` for your case. More info about pattern tokenizer can be found at http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-tokenizer.html